# Photoshop: How to change an action's step property value?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize, actions

I have made an action that resizes an image to 30%.

How can I set that value to 40%, preferably without having to make a new action?

I have highlighted the area that I would like to change:

[image]

Comment: I believe you are referring to an action instead of a macro no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by macro you mean *action*, you should be able to go to the Actions panel, find the spot in your action which says "image size," and double-click it. The red Record button will come on. Put in 40%.

Comment: If I double click on action it well be launched.

Comment: I didn't say double-click on the *action*. I said to double-click on "Image size," which is one of the *steps* of your action.

Comment: OK, that's right, I could not do it because there was no file opened.

Comment: doesnt work for me, none of the steps in my actions which have parameters like this are editable, i.e. nothing happens if I double click on the step.  No steps values are editable for me - if I want to change image size, jpeg quality etc, the only option is to re-record those steps. It is a huge limitation for actions that you cant edit any properties of steps.